# Multithreading issue with Autofac in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework, autofac

I am working with a WPF based application and using Autofac to resolve the dependency of DbContext of Entityframework. I used the below code to register my data module.

```
public class DataModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<DataContext>()
            .As<IDbContext>()
            .WithParameter("nameOrConnectionString", "DefaultConnectionString")
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
            .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

This works fine while using in normal scenario but while using TPL, due to simultaneous calls to repository, it creates error stating that "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open."

In web application, this can be resolved using InstancePerRequest to resolve dependency per request but in WPF I need to resolve this dependency per Thread request. Is there any way out for this?

I have review InstancePerRequest summary or autofac and it states that this method is used for Web request only:

```
// Summary:
//     Share one instance of the component within the context of a single web/HTTP/API
//     request. Only available for integration that supports per-request dependencies
//     (e.g., MVC, Web API, web forms, etc.).
```

**Update:**

This is a simple async method that I used to get the data:

```
 private async void OnLoadClientDetail()
    {
        long clientId = SelectedClient != null ? SelectedClient.Id : 0;
        var listOfCollection = await _collectionService.GetCollectedCollectionAsync(clientId);
        CollectionList = new ObservableCollection<CollectedCollection>(listOfCollection);
    }
```

Here OnLoadClientDetail is bound to selection change event of a combobox. When user change the selection frequently then this method will be called multiple times. The _collectionService is injected in the viewmodel and has InstancePerLifetimeScope define. So how can I get different scope for all this calls?

Comment: Why do you need to have instance per thread?

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo Actually there are multiple threads accessing the same SQL table due to which the table is locked and I got exception  "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is open."

Comment: This is exactly where the `InstancePerLifetimeScope` is meant for. You wrap a logical unit of work inside a lifetime scope and resolve from that scope. This ensures that every unit of work has its own `DataContext` and this prevents sharing of instances across threads or operations.

Comment: @Steven My service layer is injected in the viewmodel and multiple calls will be done in the same viewmodel. I have edit my post. Can you provide some sample code regarding this?

Comment: The solution is to not inject the service but resolve it from a scope and call it.

Comment: You're sharing the service, get an error, and after that asking why it's an error during sharing. Why don't you just stop injecting the shared service inside ViewModel and resolve it during method call?

Comment: @Steven Ok so basically you want to say that I need to create new instance for every thread. Its like creating new object every time to make service call. Is it correct?

Comment: Every thread should get its own object graph. This object graph could consist of objects that are shared across threads, but services should not be passed on to other threads by application code. This should be encapsulated inside the Composition Root.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you share the `_collectionService` instance across the different event handlers by injecting it by [Constructor Injection](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html).

It probably better to use [Method Injection](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html) here, so you'll get the instance per call, as you need, resolving it before method:

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    var result = new MyObjectType();
    var dep = c.Resolve<TheDependency>();
    result.SetTheDependency(dep);
    return result;
});
```